# Windows service cannot see Shell_TrayWnd

Tags: windows, service, taskbar

I need to hide the taskbar and start button via a Windows service.

In a console program I can successfully call `FindWindow` and/or `EnumWindows` to get the `"Shell_TrayWnd"` window and then hide it using `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE)`.

But when the service performs `FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL)` it returns `NULL`, and when the service performs `EnumWindows` it gets an incomplete list which does not include the `"Shell_TrayWnd"` window.

Can anyone suggest how a service can see the `"Shell_TrayWnd"` window, or suggest an alternative method for hiding the taskbar and start button (that works in a service)? Thanks.

Comment: Services usually run under a virtual desktop that isn't visible. See if this helps though: http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/

Comment: Apparently the option in the previous link was removed after XP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service#Developing_a_Windows_service

Comment: On one hand, I'm happy with a WinXP solution, at least for the time being. On the other hand, I've trying OR-ing 0x100 into the service's Type value, then restart the service, but the service still cannot see the desktop windows including the taskbar and start button. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way for a service to access windows.  It's a (designed) limitation for services.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to provide a UI (or otherwise interact with UI elements) for a service is to provide a GUI client that runs in the user's context and uses some IPC method (possibly RPC, possibly message-passing) to communicate with the service.  UI processing within privileged services is and always has been a security hole.

If you simply want a computer-wise process to kill the taskbar, then a service is neither needed nor helpful.  Configure a scheduled task to run at login.  Or set the registry to launch a custom shell instead of explorer.exe.  You aren't doing anything that requires privilege other than the user's own account.

To avoid blinking a console window, build your program for the `WINDOWS` subsystem, or use `editbin /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` to change the flags in the PE header after build is complete.